# URL redirects; for general purpose use, which is better: server-side or client-side?

Tags: http, url, redirect, seo, webserver

Take a very simple case as an example, say I have this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/65167.html
```

and I wish to serve that content under:

```
http://www.example.com/about
```

**UPDATE**: Note that the 'bad' URL is the canonical one (it's produced by a CMS which uses it internally for linking), so `"/about"` is just a way of polishing it.

I have two broad options: a server-side redirect or a client-side one. I always thought that server-side would be preferable since it's more efficient, i.e. HTTP traffic is approximately halved. However, SEO techniques tend to favour a single URL for a resource, thus client-side is to be preferred.

How do you resolve this conflict, and are there other factors I've omitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache HTTPD's mod_rewrite can leave a browser showing a SEO-friendly URL in its location bar while redirecting to a numeric URL on the server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/about$ /65167.html [L]
```

Comment: While that's an option, it doesn't solve the problem: two URLs still exist for the same resource. In fact, the horrible nasty one is the canonical one (I'll update the question to mention that), so I don't think this fix is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You could use another redirect rule to ‘hide’ the 65157.html URL from incoming requests. Using remapping on the server side, a search engine has no way to know what is ‘canonical’ anyway, so if you don't link to the ‘ugly’ URL they probably won't pick it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, as per my question-edit, the CMS that generates these URLs also generates links to them, so they will remain public.

Comment: Urgh! In that case you would have to make the ‘(id).html’ 301 to the ‘about’, then mod_rewrite the ‘about’ back to the ‘(id).html’. And yes, that would involve an unnecessary HTTP request for each page, and might slow down Googlejuice propagation. Better plan: fix the CMS to link to the right URL.

Answer (score 3):

A 301 is the wrong approach for this problem if you're redirecting from /about to /65167.html. Your CMS will only understand the 65167.html
request but a 301 is basically telling Google that /about no longer exists and to index the 65167.html page.

Ignacio is correct. You need to implement either mod_rewrite or something similar depending on your platform and hide the CMS assuming that you can actually re-write all your CMS generated links to something more friendly.

A client side redirect is probably too complex to implement and a server side redirect will cause two requests to the server.

Comment: You are right Michael. I don't know what I was thinking. I'll remove my stupid answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure Google understands [301 Moved Permanently](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2).